# PHP and HTML - Hiding a <form> when a user is logged in

Tags: php, css, html, show-hide

I asked a very similar question and I approved an answer as I thought it had done the job but it hasnt! for the life of me I can't understand why this wont work! I want a form in html to dissapear when the user is logged in! Heres my code so far! (I wont display all code as the html is loooong but I think this is relevent, please bear in mind I am at the early beginner stage of php):

I have this at the top of my page:

```
    <?php
if (isset($_GET['showerror']))
$errorcode = $_GET['showerror'];
else
$errorcode = 0;
?>
```

Then the code to try and hide the form and to display an error if the username/password is incorrect:

```
<?php
if ($errorcode == 1)
    {
    echo "<h3>Your login has failed. Try again</h3>";
    }
?>

<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['is_logged_in'])) {
?>

<form id="login" name="login" action="logincheck.php" method="post">
            User Name: 
            <input type="text" name="username"></input>
            Password: 
            <input type="password" name="password"></input>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="login"></input>
            <a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="popup('register.html')" > (Register)</a>
            <br /><br /><br />
        </form>
<?
}
?>
```

The next code is what I wrote to check if the login credentials are correct, and to turn us back to the index.html page, I assign a value to errorcode so I can display the error message if the credentials are wrong and I assign a value to is_logged_in to hide the form if they are correct. In both instances we are turned back to index.html but hopefully either with a form on display and an eroor message, or no form and no message: (dbconn.php is my connection to the mysql database)

```
    <?php
session_start();
require "dbconn.php";

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE name ='".$username."' AND password='".$password."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );

if ($row != null)
    {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['name'];
        header("Location: index.html?is_logged_in=1?");
    exit();
    }
 else
    {
    header("Location: index.html?showerror=1");
     exit();
    }
?>
```

but the problem is that neither of the two outcomes, I get no error message and I get no hidden form, because nothing is happening it is difficult for me to gauge where I am going wrong!

Thank you sooooo much for any help... I spent ages setting up xampp properly and got ready to learn lots but I have been stuck here for a good few hours now!

EDIT: still getting to grips with this code editing! didnt display some of code but I think its done now!

Comment: Anyway you should use mysql_real_escape_string() for $username and $password!

Comment: I will look it up, I am absolute beginner so no hard encrypting or anything.... just trying to get to grips with the basic functionality!

Comment: i see two things that look fishy to me, but i'm not sure enough about them to want to post an answer... anyways: 1) doesn't session_start() always have to be at the very top of every php-document it's used in? try moving it to the top of all pages it's used in. and 2) the second question mark of `header("Location: index.html?is_logged_in=1?");` looks wrong too. what happens if you change these two things?

Comment: True, session_start() should be in the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't set the session variable is_logged_in, put

```
$_SESSION["is_logged_in"] = 1;
```

into the login file (between the brackets if $row != null)

Answer (score 0):

When you check for a session when you want to hide the form, you're looking for `$_SESSION['is_logged_in']`, yet you aren't setting that session when the user logs in - just a session var for `username`. You need to add something like:

```
$_SESSION['is_logged_in'] = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm,

I think you might be missing the statement to set the value of $_SESSION['is_logged_in'] in your logic that runs after successful validation.

Adding in

```
$_SESSION['is_logged_in'] = "1";
```

into your if ($row != null) condition should do the trick. =)

The reason for this is that you are checking for the Session variable named is_logged_in, but it does not exist as it has not been set by your code.

Alternatively, you can check for "$_SESSION['name']" instead in your 'isset' if statement.

On a sidenote, its a good practice to escape the string you are going to use as part of your SQL statement. Using PHP, one easy way of doing that is via the mysql_real_escape_string function built into PHP. Allowing the user input to pass directly into your SQL statement could result in [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks, which is a very dangerous thing. =D

Answer (score 0):

You can use style to hide your form:

```
.form
{
 display:block;
}

.form error
{
 display:none;
}
```

use a little trick with jquery by use this api addClass() to add a new class for your form you can hide it.

But I suggest when a user enter a wrong password or wrong username, your error should be placed next to the form and the user can enter the username and password again.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['is_logged_in']))
```

To:

```
if (!empty($_GET['is_logged_in']))
```

But then again, you need to understand this is a very unsafe way to verify user credentials. You should never pass these kinds of variables in URL parameters becuase a user could simply fake their log in by writing a URL like:

```
www.site.com?is_logged_in=lolhacked
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

<del>Important use **mysql_real_escape_string** on all USER INPUT, or you could hacked very easily</del> SEE comment from Dan Kanze. But its better to learn the MYSQLI extension Prepared Statements, its easier cleaner and securer
Here a example.
http://mattbango.com/notebook/web-development/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/

Also this code is not very secure, cause a user can set $_GET['is_logged_in'] !== "1" manuell, you should maybe add a cookie to the user pc, with a unique value, that the user is logged in and that value matches his user/pass pair, which you store in your DB..

Just google secure login form php or something like that.

```
 <?php


require "dbconn.php";


if(@$_GET['showerror'] == "1"){
    echo "Your login has failed. Try again";
    exit;
}


if(!empty($_POST['username']){
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); 
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE name ='".$username."' AND password='".$password."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
    if(!empty($row)){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['name']; 
        header("Location: index.html?is_logged_in=1?";
        exit(); 
    }else{
        header("Location: index.html?showerror=1"); 
        exit(); 
    }
}

if(@$_GET['is_logged_in'] !== "1"){
    // DISPLAY FORM
}else{
    // DO YOUR STUFF
}

?>
```

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string is depricated and can be used for blind sql injection attacks. do not use this.

Comment: oh, i dont use it anymore, only prepared statements, i edit my answer. Thanks for letting know.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm very new to PHP and still learning myself. One thing I can tell you is that you are going to need to encrypt your password. use "md5($password);" There is other encryption algorithm out there, but to me it seems like md5 is most commonly used.

As for the login script, one thing I learned quick from other programmers is to use $_GET[] when it's needed. Like ?Page=, ?viewphoto=, etc. Do not store the state of the "logged in" in the url. use cookies! :)

One other thing, "mysql_real_escape_string()" you are going to need to use them!!!!!! or hackers will run Sql injection script easily. look at the php pages on how to use them.

I'm not saying my code is right (again still very new to php).

```
if(!count($err))
{
    $_POST['username'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $_POST['password'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $_POST['rememberMe'] = (int)$_POST['rememberMe'];

    // Escaping all input data

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id,usr FROM {$bd_prefix}Members WHERE usr='{$_POST['username']}' AND pass='".md5($_POST['password'])."'"));

    if($row['usr'])
    {
        // If everything is OK login

        $_SESSION['usr']= $row['usr'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['rememberMe'] = $_POST['rememberMe'];
        $_SESSION['logged'] = true;
```

This is just the beginning to my login script that I coded a year again. I know that some of the code may not be correctly coded, and there might be better ways of doing this. but it worked for me at the time.